# How to kill mapreduce running job on google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I started map reduce job on google app engine but I could not stop it. It is just running and could not find a way to kill it. By looking into already asked questions, I deleted all tasks from default queue and even paused queue but still mapper call-back function is running and eating all my free quota every day in a hour. GAE is just making me frustrating...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the MR job is running on the default task queue (it is configurable)? MR uses the task queue to invoke itself. If there are no tasks in the queue (and nothing is currently executing) the job can't proceed. A task is rescheduling itself, so if there was a running task while you were clearing the queue it is possible that it may schedule itself after you cleared. Pausing the queue, waiting a bit (to make sure nothing is running) and clearing it should do the job.